# Flutter setState() make a loop to be always recalled

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a code like this below, the simple flow is I make a loop from a list of objects to create some widgets.

```
class ScoringAttribute {
  int _id;
  bool _isdelete;
  double _scorehigh, _scorelow, _scorevalue;
  String _name, _scoretype, _description, _title;
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List dataScoringAttributes;
  List<ScoringAttribute> listScoringAttributeObjects = new List<ScoringAttribute>();

  final String urlPresentation = ".../.resentations/getPresentations";
  final String urlScoringAttribute = ".../.scoringattributes/getScoringattributes";

  Future<String> getPresentationData() async {
    var responseScoringAttribute = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(urlScoringAttribute),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    );

    var scoringAttributeJson = json.decode(responseScoringAttribute.body);

    dataScoringAttributes = scoringAttributeJson['scoringattributes'];

    for(int i = 0; i < dataScoringAttributes.length; i++) {
      var scoringAttributeObject = new ScoringAttribute();

      scoringAttributeObject._id = dataScoringAttributes[i]["id"];
      scoringAttributeObject._description = dataScoringAttributes[i]["iddescription"];
      scoringAttributeObject._isdelete = dataScoringAttributes[i]["isdelete"];
      scoringAttributeObject._name = dataScoringAttributes[i]["name"];
      scoringAttributeObject._scorehigh = double.parse(dataScoringAttributes[i]["scorehigh"].toString());
      scoringAttributeObject._scorelow = double.parse(dataScoringAttributes[i]["scorelow"].toString());
      scoringAttributeObject._scoretype = dataScoringAttributes[i]["scoretype"];
      scoringAttributeObject._title = dataScoringAttributes[i]["title"];
      scoringAttributeObject._scorevalue = double.parse(dataScoringAttributes[i]["scorelow"].toString());
      
      listScoringAttributeObjects.add(scoringAttributeObject);
    }

    return "Success";
  }

  List<Widget> scoringAttributeList() {
    List<Widget> list = new List();
    for(int i = 0; i < listScoringAttributeObjects.length; i++) {
      if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "slider") {
        list.add(
          new Container(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //THE SLIDER VALUE TEXT
                    new Text(
                      //CONVERT DOUBLE TYPE TO STRING WITHOUT DECIMAL POINTS
                      listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorevalue.toStringAsFixed(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorevalue.truncateToDouble() == listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorevalue ? 0 : 0),
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 28.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    //THE SLIDER
                    new Slider(
                      activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      inactiveColor: const Color(0xFFb7d2e0),
                      min: double.parse(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorelow.toString()),
                      max: double.parse(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorehigh.toString()),
                      value: double.parse(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorevalue.toString()),
                      onChanged: (double value) {
                        setState(() {
                          listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorevalue = double.parse(value.round().toString());
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      else if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "text_field") {
        list.add(...);
      }
      else if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "stars") {
        list.add(...);
      }
      else if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "thumb") {
        list.add(new Container(...);
      }
    }
    
    return list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<String> (
        future: getPresentationData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Column(
                  children: scoringAttributeList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are some different widgets depending on the type, and there are 4 types, and 1 type might have more than 1 widget in it, so I make the loop depend on the data that it got from DB.

The problem is I don't know why every time I use `setState()` inside the loop, it always processes the loop again, so it'll be an infinite loop to create a new widget, and it'll duplicate the widget from the beginning (only happen when the setState() is called).

Ex: there are 4 data inside the List, and if the `setState()` is called, it'll show 8 data (show the first 4 data twice)

Here's the example of how I setState() into the data inside the List

```
onChanged: (double value) {
    setState(() {
      listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scorevalue = double.parse(value.round().toString());
    });
},
```

I think the problem is because I `setState()` into some data inside the List. So when the List state is changed, it'll re-render anything that is related to the List.

Is it true?

If yes, is there any other solution how to change my code?
If not, is there any mistake in my code or my logic maybe?

Thank you. Really looking forward to some solution about this, cause I really got stuck in this, and its already been a week :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple move your `getPresentationData()` into **state variable**. So that it will get `triggered` only **once**.

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Future<String> _presentationFuture;

  initState() {
   _presentationFuture = getPresentationData()
  }
//other contents

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<String> (
    future: _presentationFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData) {
```

**Reason for duplicate:** we can calling `setState` on Slider dataChange which will re-render the `HomePageState` which will again trigger the `network` call (`getPresentationData()`)

Note: If you want to trigger network on slider change, clear the list before making a network call

```
Future<String> getPresentationData() async {
listScoringAttributeObjects = new List<ScoringAttribute>(); // clear data
var responseScoringAttribute = await http.get(
  Uri.encodeFull(urlScoringAttribute),
  headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this would be related to the one `setState()` in your code. It is only called when the slider is used.

I think the problem is caused by list.add(...); in scoringAttributeList(). You shouldn't modify data when build() is executed.

You should assume that `build()` can be called repeatedly and at any time.
Build your code so that this doesn't cause issues when it happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but your statement "I think the problem is caused by list.add(...); in scoringAttributeList(). You shouldn't modify data when build() is executed.", i think i'm not modify the data when build() is executed (it'll show error anyway), i modify the data with setState() only on the onChange() handler, when every single widget is already build.

Comment: `scoringAttributeList` is called from build and contains `else if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "text_field") {
        list.add(...);
      }
      else if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "stars") {
        list.add(...);
      }
      else if(listScoringAttributeObjects[i]._scoretype == "thumb") {
        list.add(new Container(...);
      }`

Comment: Oh i see, i'm sorry that i dont write the full code, cause its too much and not needed, the . . . is actually the same with the scoretype "slider" i dont do setState() during build, i add the setState() on onChange() handler. By the way I already found the right answer for this problem from Dinesh Balasubramanian. Thank you for your response, really appreciate it. :)